# How to add an async validator to a CUSTOM field?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Does anyone know how to declare an **ASYNC validation method ON THE CLASS of a custom field**?

Right now I have a **sync validator** in the `validate()` method:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-field',
  template: `<p>Some markup</p>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyFieldComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyFieldComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class MyFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    // return null or error
  }

  // Rest of the code omitted for brevity
  // writeValue(), registerOnChange()...
}
```

But even if I add the `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` to the providers using the same syntax as above, it doesn't let me declare something like a `validateAsync()` method.

Unless... both types of validator target the `validate()` method and I need to do *both my sync and async validations* in this method and *return one big observable* (potentially wrapping multiple error keys)? I'm not too sure about this.

SIDE NOTE: What I could get to work is declaring the async validator **directly in the providers**, either inline with `useValue` or as a separate class with `useClass`. But I'd like to have it **as a method on the component class** with `useExisting`.

Comment: What is the `FieldEntityReferenceComponent`?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste gone wrong... it should say `MyFieldComponent`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't completely understand what is your requirement but i can give you some idea that maybe will help you.

So let start with our custom field that implements `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator` (sync):

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-field',
  template: `<p>Some markup</p>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyFieldComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyFieldComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class MyFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  validationResult: any;

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    this.validationResult = { 'sync': true };
    return null;
  }
}
```

After that declare directive that will implement `AsyncValidator`:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: 'my-field[formControlName],my-field[ngModel]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomAsyncValidator),
    multi: true
  }]
})
class CustomAsyncValidator implements AsyncValidator {

  valueAccessor: MyFieldComponent;

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[]) {
    this.valueAccessor = valueAccessors.find(x => x.constructor === MyFieldComponent) as MyFieldComponent;
  }

  // the same as above. I would use it
  // constructor(@Self() private valueAccessor: MyFieldComponent) {}


  /**
   * presents global validation result async + sync
   */ 
  validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(fakeAsyncValidator(1000)(control)).map(asyncResult => {
      return Object.assign({}, asyncResult, this.valueAccessor.validationResult);
    });
  }
}


function fakeAsyncValidator(timeout: number = 0) {
  return (c: AbstractControl) => {
    let resolve: (result: any) => void;
    const promise = new Promise(res => { resolve = res; });
    const res = { 'async': false };
    setTimeout(() => resolve(res), timeout);
    return promise;
  };
}
```

In the directive above we use the same selector as our custom field (`my-field`), provide `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` and also inject existing component in constructor(you can notice two options).

And finally we have `validate` method in this directive that is trying to do something similar what you want.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3FVwIoZrR0JTEwAHyvFU?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time, yurzui. The rationale is that when a validator is only ever gonna be used by one field and one field only, it feels more cohesive to make it a part of the field code. Also, since we're talking about an async validator that needs to use `Http`, it *must* belong to some kind of Angular construct which supports dependency injection (either a directive or a component); it couldn't be a mere function or class. Now, you did provide some insight with your answer and I have a few questions... (to be continued in next comment)

Comment: Great idea to have the directive match the selector of the field. That way, the directive gets applied to the custom field automagically. Now can you explain the optional injection in `CustomAsyncValidator`'s constructor? I get that it lets the async validator access the result from the sync validator, but is it really required? What if both `validate()` methods (sync + async) return their values **separately**, wouldn't they be merged automatically?

Comment: Yes. i am getting access to the sync validator, `@Options` is used to prevent error when it is not defined. And i just noticed how angular2 does it https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-rc.2/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L102 i am not sure about merging it automatically. Angular uses the same technic(`Great idea to have the directive match the selector of the field`) to communicate between directives https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-rc.2/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts#L45-L48

Answer (score 0):

I followed the sample of the directive. But I a somehow different approach on the end since I haven't had a clue how to set up the Validator properly. It did cost me some effort to figure out how to properly set up the whole stuff. Since the question is hit many times I thought I'll post my conclusions.

I retrieve the component I'm interested in from the constructor like

```
constructor(@Self() private valueAccessor: RefURLcheckComponent) {}
```

and within in the `validate` function I set the `errors` from the custom component

```
this.valueAccessor.setErrors(ret);
```

The approach works well for sync and async validators at the same time. Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-newktr?file=src/app/validators/checkUrlResolveDirective.ts)